# executor for creating thread pool for server

Tags: java, multithreading

I found this java code online in whoch threads are getting created when a client requests a connection from a server:

```
while (!executor.isShutdown()) 
{
    try 
    {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        executor.execute(new FileServerHandler(socket));
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // handle exception
    }
}



public void shutdown() 
{
    executor.shutdown();

    try 
    {
        serverSocket.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

As per my understanding, if `executor.isShutdown()` is `true`, then the server should:

> Stop accepting new client requests.

> Let the threads who are currently in the queue or are active finish first.

But wouldn't the control flow in `while` loop be sitting on `accept()` which is a blocking call - and in case no other client connect request comes, the control will still be in the loop despite having the `executor.isShutdown()` condition as `true`?

Comment: The main documentation for `execute()` says: "Executes the given command at some time in the future. The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation." So the method has discretion to not use the thread pool at all.  Also some implementations such as `ThreadPoolExecutor` will throw `RejectedExecutionException` if the pool is shutdown.  Basically random code you found isn't great.

Comment: @markspace Let's say that the executor is shutdown - in this case as well the flow will be at `accept()` and the flow will still be stuck waiting for new clients?

Comment: Fundamentally, you need to test code in your actual application to understand if it will work for you.  I outlined some of the possible scenarios already.

Comment: Write some actual code, with a specific `Executor` implementation, and test it. Have you read the Javadoc for `accept()`? What do you think might happen when you call `close` from another thread? (I don't know the answer, but you can find out by trying it)

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus, Re, "...still be stuck waiting for new clients?" It will be stuck until _one_ client tries to connect. It will accept that client connection, and then the server thread will throw `RejectedExecutionException`. What happens next depends on how that server thread handles the exception. Meanwhile, the client will be sending some kind of request and awaiting a reply. Too bad for them, 'cause the connection probably will be closed by the server's OS before any reply is sent.